# Fast port connection and ability to daisy chain unmanaged switches on Cisco Catalyst

Tags: cisco, ethernet, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, spanning-tree

I have a Cisco Catalyst 2960-S that I use in a home environment.

In the configuration I currently have (very basic, basically just `switchport mode trunk` on upstream and `switchport mode access` on reset of ports) it takes about 45 seconds for ethernet devices to establish a connection (and switch link lights to go green) when I plug them in to the switch. With the same router but using an unmanaged switch, it takes under 2 seconds for the same devices to connect to the network.

After doing some research, I found that this is [due to the default STP setup](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/take-too-much-time-to-get-an-ip-over-a-cisco-switch/td-p/2895550) and the solution is to set my ports to `spanning-tree portfast` mode. I was able to confirm this was the problem by temporarily switching a port to this mode, and devices plugged into that port instantly connected, but all other ports still took 45-60 seconds.

The problem I'm reading with `spanning-tree portfast` is that it prevents me from connecting a plain old unmanaged switch to the pordtfast ports. Since the Cisco switch ports go around the house and sometimes I temporarily connect an unmanaged switch to a port that usually is connected to a PC.

Is there a configuration option that both quickly connects to hosts and also allows me to connect unmanaged switches to any of the ports when I want without having to drop in on the switch and update the STP mode every time?

I have seen a little bit of info suggesting `spanning-tree portfast bpduguard default` might get me closer but I don't want to blindly apply this without knowing for sure it's what I need.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Using `portfast` on access ports does not prevent you from connecting unmanaged switches. `bpduguard` is no help here, see the linked question. However, home networking is explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].